# Scalar Particles, Flavor Changing Processes and Gauge Symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

Let's consider an extended version of the Standard Model (SM) with a new Yukawa operator of the form
$$ \sum_\ell g_\ell\bar{\ell}\ell \phi ,$$
where $\ell$ is any lepton of the SM and $\phi$ is a new real spin-0 particle, which is assumed to be a singlet of $SU(2)_L$. This new term breaks the $SU(2)_L$ symmetry, but I'll not try to justify its existence.

---

Now, my question:

- I want to compute the loop correction to the vertex $\mu e\phi$, which does not exist in the original theory. One possible contribution for this term is show in the figure below (where I also suppose that neutrinos are massive). Does something guarantee that this loop computation will give a finite result in the framework presented here?

$\hspace{6.5cm}$[image],

- If this is not the case, what conditions must be imposed to the lagrangian in order to have finite contributions? Is it enough to have a Hamiltonian with dimension $d\leq4$ operators? Or is it essential to have a perfectly defined gauge theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are considering massless neutrinos there is no such a diagram since all interactions would preserve flavor.
If you take instead massive neutrinos, you are probing lepton flavor violation within the SM since the new interaction with $\varphi$ respects flavor. It is thus very very small, being controlled by the neutrino masses. In turn, it is therefore clear that this diagram is finite since you need to do a mass insertion which makes the integral convergent enough.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But I still don't see why this diagram is finite. If $k$ is the momentum running in the loop, each neutrino propagator comes with $k^{-1}$ and the gauge boson propagator with $k^{-2}$. So, I have something like $\int \frac{dk^4}{k^4}$, which is logarithmically divergent. Where do I get wrong?

Comment: this maximally divergent contribution to the integrand is flavor preserving since it knows nothing about the neutrino masses that you have just drop in the power counting. The next term that depends on neutrino masses, the only that can give you off-diagonal flavor terms, must have (at least) an extra $m_\nu/k$ term which makes the integral UV convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. Now, another question: what if neutrinos were very heavy? In this case I cannot make a Taylor expansion in $m_\nu/k$, as you did. Do you think that the diagram would still be finite?

Comment: yes, it would be finite. Because no matter how large the mass is, the divergent part of the integral is mass independent and therefore flavor preserving.

Comment: Thank you again! So, you are supposing that the coupling $g_\nu$ is universal for the different neutrinos. What if this is not true? In this case I can't recall PMNS matrix unitarity to get rid of the divergent term.

Comment: If the coupling $g_\nu$ isn't multiple of the identity in flavor space then the divergent part of that diagram will not be generically be zero. The reason is that $g_\nu$ is another source of flavor violation in addition to the neutrino mass matrix (think about it before diagonalizing the neutrino masses). Technically, you can see that the usual GIM mechanism fails: $V_{ei}V_{\mu i}^* g^{(\nu)}_i\neq 0$ for $g^{(\nu)}_i$ that depends on i.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. :) But in principle, there should be other contributions that would cancel the divergent part of this observable. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes, by definition of renormalization you can always reabosorb the divergences in a bare parameter tof the lagrangian. In the case at hand you need it to contain $\bar{e}\mu\varphi+ h.c.$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The idea of adding flavor changing counter-terms sounds strange for me, but I agree with you. The flavor symmetry is only an accidental symmetry in the SM. One (possible) last question: Do you know how to fix the on-shell condition of this counter-term?

Comment: It is up to you. For example, you can define the coupling at zero external momentum and subtract therefore the divergent part with this choice.